# Check what kind of parameters shell script got

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob

I need some help in my shell script. I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $*
do
   if [[ $i = *[a-zA-Z] ]]
      then echo $i contains just letters.
   elif [[ $i = *[a-zA-Z0-9] ]]
      then echo $i contains numbers and letters.
   else
      echo Error.
done
```

I would like the result to be, for example:

```
$ ./script.sh abCd a9d a-b
abCd contains just letters.  
a9d contains numbers and letters.  
Error.
```

But I get `contains just letters` in every case.

I also tried grep command too, but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegEx are wrong. Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $*
do
   if [[ $i =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
      then echo $i contains just letters.
   elif [[ $i =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ ]]
      then echo $i contains numbers and letters.
   else
      echo Error.
   fi
done
```

Comment: @N.Tom Glad I could help. Thanks for posting a question with complete code and a useful testcase. A little hint for your program: the second case only checks whether at least one of the characters is in the string. So if you only use a number as an input it will still output "9 contains numbers and letters". Just a little semantic *problem* when only using a number as an input.